# Clear Oracle database shard state

Tags: oracle, sharding

Have had some problems with Oracle sharding infrastructure configuration. Particularly added a shard into wrong shard space. Removed it (probably needed to move the chunks first) with `-force` option and tried to add again. Since then the shard is added in incorrect state and I haven't found a way to fix it.

Just FYI:

```
GDSCTL>config shard
Name                Shard Group         Status    State       Region     Availability
----                -----------         ------    -----       ---------- --------
ape002              shrdgrp_oper        Ok        Replicated  reg_oper   PENDING
ape003              shrdgrp_arch        Ok        Replicated  reg_arch   PENDING
```

Now have dropped the three DBs (two shards and the shard catalog), created them again, and going to start over the configaration process.

The querstion: How to clear all sharding-related information from a DB without recreation?

Comment: I guessyou should move it to the [Database Administrator site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) where you have better chances to get answer

Comment: thanks, done: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/225839/clear-oracle-database-shard-state